# Python: how can I move a file into a folder without overwriting it with the one already present?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def upload_image(): 
    if lista_interventi.focus(): 
        folder_check=Path(r"C:\GEC\image_DB")
    if not folder_check.is_dir():
        os.makedirs(r"C:\GEC\image_DB")
        image = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="", title="Seleziona il file",filetypes=(("jpg files", ".jpg"),("all files","(.xls")))
        shutil.move(image, r"C:\GEC\image_DB"+"\"+ entry_claim.get()+ ".jpg") 
        messagebox.showinfo("Operazione riuscita", "Immagine inserita") 
    else: ### missing code
```

Comment: Python code without newlines and indentation is nonsense. Please post code that makes sense.

Comment: Enclose your code in between triple backticks (\`\`\`) to get it properly formatted

Comment: You can't have two things with the same name in the same place

Comment: I'd want to add an increasing number fo to the new file --example "string_01"...

Comment: You check if file exist and if exist you append _1 or whatever format you want.  If _1 exist then change it to _2 and check again until something comes back as free to use. Its not a difficult logic to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that can take the source folder, destination folder and file name and move it while also checking if name exist and appending a count if need be.

```
import shutil
import os


source_dir = './images'
target_dir = './images2'
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)


def move_file(from_dir, to_dir, file_name, addition=None):
    if addition is None:
        addition = 1
        path = f'{to_dir}/{file_name}'
    else:
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(f'{to_dir}/{file_name}')
        path = f'{filename} ({addition}){file_extension}'.strip()

        addition += 1
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        move_file(from_dir, to_dir, file_name, addition)
    else:
        shutil.copy(f'{from_dir}/{file_name}', path)


for file_name in file_names:
    move_file(source_dir, target_dir, file_name)
```

In my case the before and after look like this:

Before structure of folders:

[image]

After:

[image]

As you can see the file `darkred.png` existed and so did `darkred (1).png` so the function correctly renamed the file `darkred (2).png` and moved it.